# Finding the Largest Digit in C++

Tags: c++, math

1. Input a 3-digit integer.
2. Print the largest digit in the integer (Tip: use % 10 to get the rightmost digit, and / 10 to remove the rightmost digit).

```
Input: 173
Expected Output: 7
```

We were given this activity 2 days old and still couldn't solve this mystery. Here's my own code which doesn't match the given expected output above:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   int num, result;

   cin >> num;
    if(num > 0) {
        result = num % 10;
        num / 10;
        cout << result;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You separate only the last digit, but need to check all - just add a loop. Also `num / 10` does nothing.

```
 maxdigit = 0;
 while (num > 0) {
      maxdigit = max(maxdigit, num % 10);
      num /= 10;
  }
 cout << maxdigit;
```

Comment: @Julian Williams Is my answer still unclear?

Answer (score 2):

Different way to solve the problem. Take the input as a string. You can handle much larger numbers and the string is already decomposed into digits. You barely have to think. Just work through the string character-by-character, make sure the character is a digit, and keep track of the biggest digit seen so far.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <cctype> // needed for isdigit
//using namespace std; Not recommended. Causes problems

int main() 
{
    std::string num;
    char max = 0;
    std::cin >> num; // read number as a string.
    for (char ch: num)
    { //iterate string character by character
        if (!isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)))
        { // if we didn't get a digit, the user screwed up (or is a jerk)
          // Let's not assume malice and let them know they've made a mistake.
            std::cerr << "Must input a valid number";
            return -1;
        }
        if (ch > max)
        { // this is the biggest character seen so far.
            max = ch; // update biggest
        }
    }
    std::cout << max; // print biggest
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of MBo is the best and should be accepted.

You are obviously not allowed to use C++ algorithms yet. And, maybe you are learing now about interger and modulo divisions.

If you would be allowed to use more advanced C++, you would probably write something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    if (std::string number{}; (std::cin >> number) and std::all_of(number.begin(), number.end(), ::isdigit))
        std::cout << *max_element(number.begin(), number.end()) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working example **without using** loops and **without using** `std::max`. Note this(without loop) is just one among many possible ways of doing it.

```
#include <iostream>
int findDigit(int passed_num, int current_num)
{
    
    int lastDigit;
  
    
    if (passed_num == 0) {
     
        return current_num;
    }
 
    // find the last didit
    lastDigit = passed_num % 10;

    if(lastDigit > current_num)
    {
      
         current_num = lastDigit;
    }
    
  
         //call findDigit() repeatedly
        current_num = findDigit(passed_num / 10, current_num);
  
        std::cout<<lastDigit<<" ";
    
    return current_num;
}
  
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int input_num, greatest_num;
    std::cin>>input_num;
    
    greatest_num = findDigit(input_num, 0);
    
    std::cout<<"greatest is: "<<greatest_num<<std::endl;
    
    std::cout<<"Enter another number: ";
    std::cin>>input_num;
    
    greatest_num = findDigit(input_num, 0);
    
    std::cout<<"greatest is: "<<greatest_num<<std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above is as follows:

```
Enter a number: 24344357
2 4 3 4 4 3 5 7 greatest is: 7
Enter another number: 2353639
2 3 5 3 6 3 9 greatest is: 9
```

Comment: Why would you avoid loops here? And if you were avoiding loops, why not just rely on the fact that the input has three digits? And note that your solution doesn’t work if called a second time.

Comment: I have added the version of the program that works as many times as you want. Check my edit. Also the reason i wrote this program without any loops is that i wanted to show that we don't always have to use loops. That is it is possible to do this without any loops. Just to show that many times in programming, there are alternate/many ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: If you wanted to do this without loops, just do `int findDigit(int i) { return i ? max(i%10, findDigit(i/10)) : 0; }`. Your organization here is unnecessarily complex and messy, and offers no benefit over using loops.

Comment: Have you read that i have neither used loop or `std::max` in the first line of my answer. Why are you suggesting the thing that i do no want  to use in the first place. Again, this question is not about how to organise your code but rather how to achieve a given result. Also, i never claimed that this is better or worse in any way than any other method suggested by others.

Comment: But it *is* worse. That’s the point. It’s like trying to program without using the letter “i”: an unnecessary, artificial constraint which makes your code worse and doesn’t help you accomplish anything.

Comment: Also sometimes these type of questions like "do this without loop" is also asked as an exercise at schools or at other places.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
   int a = 11;
   int b = 5;
   int c = 23;
 
   int max = (a>b) ? ((a>c) ? a : c) : ((b>c) ? b : c) ;
    
   cout << max << endl;
}//using Ternary Operator
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is wrong. You should not find the biggest number, but the biggest digit within a number.

Comment: @ArminMontigny Understand